# Used and total character count in PrimeFaces inputTextarea counterTemplate

Tags: primefaces

I have a question regarding primefaces. I have a textbox and I needed a character limit within that textbox as well as output text giving the current character status.

Currently, my counter looks like this:

[image]

Rather than a character count**down**, I would prefer a count**up**. Something more like "32/50 characters used".

Here is the bit of code I did to make this:

```html
<p:inputTextarea id="recommendedToolsOther" rows="4"
    style="vertical-align: top; width: 98% !important;" styleClass="preformatted"
    autoResize="false" value="#{rfeBean.rfe.otherRecommendedTools}"
    disabled="#{!rfeBean.recommendedToolsChecked[ReferralTemplateConstants.RECOMMENDED_TOOLS_HAND_OTHER]}"
    counter="displayRecTools" maxlength="50"
    counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining">
    <p:ajax event="change" update="recommendedToolsOther"/>
</p:inputTextarea>
<br/>
<h:outputText id="displayRecTools" />
```

I have an idea of how I can do this. The variable that represents the number of characters remaining is represented by R. The amount of characters used is represented by U.
I would need to do this:  U = (C-50)*(-1)

I'm just not sure how to do algebra like that on primefaces.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think its possible with the PF counter... if you wanna fall back to jQuery this works for me:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="textarea" maxlength="20" onfocus="updateCount()" onkeyup="updateCount()"/>
<div id="counter"/>
```

with

```
<script>
    function updateCount() {
        $("[id$='counter']").html($("[id$='textarea']").val().length + "/" + $("[id$='textarea']").attr('maxlength') + " characters used");
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: It is 'possible', see my answer, but I upvoted this answer anyway ;-) Curious to which answer the OP is going to accept. He had two retries after this one... weird

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with a simple overriding of the [updateCounter function of the PrimeFaces 'inputTextarea'](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/forms/forms.js#L94) widget:

Replacing

```
var remainingText = this.cfg.counterTemplate.replace('{0}', remaining);
```

with

```
var remainingText = this.cfg.counterTemplate.replace('{0}', remaining).replace('{1}', length).replace('{2}', this.cfg.maxlength);
```

Will give you the option to use {1} for the used length and {2} for the configured max length.

An example of the counterTemplate would be

```
"This textArea has used {1} of {2} characters, so {0} are remaining"
```

So the full function override becomes

```
PrimeFaces.widget.InputTextarea.prototype.updateCounter = function() {
    var value = this.normalizeNewlines(this.jq.val()),
    length = value.length;

    if(this.counter) {
        var remaining = this.cfg.maxlength - length;
        if(remaining < 0) {
            remaining = 0;
        }

        var remainingText = this.cfg.counterTemplate.replace('{0}', remaining).replace('{1}', length).replace('2', this.cfg.maxlength);

        this.counter.html(remainingText);
    }
}
```

Include this in the correct place to override the existing one and it will work

Soooo easy to use the source to find solutions...

Comment: +1. I think it's worth opening an issue at Git. It will eliminate the need to create a workaround or hardcoding to show the maximum length.

Comment: @JasperDeVries: Will do this weekend

Comment: Wow... I think I reveived a downvote by some one that created a bad answer (which I downvoted) on two other almost identical questions by the same poster... Cool!!!

Comment: Feature request added: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2338