# Count characters used in p:inputTextarea instead of characters remaining

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces

I posted a similar question earlier but I'm looking for a different approach. I have a inputTextArea and I need to limit the amount of characters that can be entered in to it as well as display the amount of characters used (ex: "31/50 characters used"). Currently, I am just using attributes for the inputTextArea to do this, however, this way, I can only get a count for the characters remaining. Below is a picture of the inputTextArea as well as the code to do this.

[Characters Remaining counter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUUgp.png)

```html
<p:inputTextarea id="ogdGacOther" rows="1" style="vertical-align: top; width: 98% !important;" styleClass="preformatted" autoResize="false" value="#{rfeBean.rfe.targetOfficerReasonsForReferral.otherOgdGac}" disabled="#{!rfeBean.ogdGacReferralReasonsChecked[ReferralTemplateConstants.OGD_GAC_OTHER] or !raudUserSessionBean.raudUser.referMode or rfeBean.workItemMissing}"
  counter="displayGacCharCount" maxlength="50" counterTemplate="{0} #{msg.rfeCharactersRemaining}">
  <p:ajax event="change" process="@this" />
</p:inputTextarea>
<br/>
<h:outputText id="displayGacCharCount" />
```

I am wondering if there is way to modify this so that it displays characters used. The {0} in the counter template, is the number that represents the amount of char remaining. If anyone know a way I could call a java method using that {0}, I would be golden. Either way, let me know what you think the best approach. I am trying to avoid using any javascript of jQuery.

I tried something like this:

```html
<h:outputText id="displayGacCharCount" value="#{rfeBean.methodToChangeCharRemainToCharUsed(valueForCharRemain({0})}" />
```

When I tried this, I got an error along the lines of "El Expression is unbalanced"

Comment: Look at the javascript source of this component in PrimeFaces github. Most likely this is all solved client-side and you can easily override some javascript function

Comment: Since I'm in a good mood: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/forms/forms.js#L94

Comment: Beeep, this is your ***THIRD*** question in on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863482/character-counter-variable-modification-in-primefaces WOW....

Comment: The error you get is because it ***IS*** unbalanced

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Character counter variable modification in primefaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863482/character-counter-variable-modification-in-primefaces)

Comment: And you are even more lucky... I answered your original question... Please accept and upvote (yes a shameless plug, but I hate people searching complex solutions when the source is open to investigate)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Liam,

It's very simple, forget the counter and get the string length:

```
<p:inputTextarea id="ogdGacOther" rows="1" maxlength="50"
              value="#{rfeBean.rfe.targetOfficerReasonsForReferral.otherOgdGac}">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" update="displayGacCharCount" global="false"/>
    <p:ajax event="keydown" update="displayGacCharCount" global="false"/>
    <p:ajax event="keypress" update="displayGacCharCount" global="false"/>
</p:inputTextarea>

<h:outputText id="displayGacCharCount" 
           value="#{rfeBean.rfe.targetOfficerReasonsForReferral.otherOgdGac.length()}"/>
```

Comment: Jikes... Every key stroke creates an ajax call... `pe:javascript` with reading the length of the value would be a little better... (or the maxlength - the remainging... )

Comment: @Kukeltje Do you think my answer is not useful? It may not be the best way, but it's a solution. PrimeFaces Extensions would require more dependency on the project, although processing will be faster. Why do not you put implementations with PrimeFaces Extensions to help us?

Comment: It might work, but in a very bad way (in my opinion, specificaly if a very simple jquery solution and a small enhancement to PrimeFaces is available.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863482/character-counter-variable-modification-in-primefaces)

Comment: You sir are a god send. I feel stupid now seeing how easy this was. Works like butter. The only difference is that I only used the ajax keyup event, only that was needed.

Comment: Many thanks @LiamPaquette, my first response had just keyup, but I put all the events because I had not done the necessary tests. I'm glad to helped you. Hugs!

Comment: .. and, how does this work when pasting text using a mouse or dragging text to the field using a mouse?

Comment: hmm.. it works just as bad as the standard PF implementation. It also does not support mouse paste and text drag...